# Old school ascii shellcode

Tags: shellcode

This part of ascii shellcode set eax at zero with the and instruction (%...). In the debugger and in pratice this PIC code work all the time but why?  the AND instruction algorithme is:

```
Operand target ← Operand target ∩ Operande Source
flag CF ← 0
flag OF ← 0
```

It's possible that the eax register is not set to zero if the previous value of eax is not good?

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    asm("\
        and eax, 0x454e4f4a;\
        and eax, 0x3a313035;\
        ");

    return 0;
}
```

compilation line:

```
gcc -m32  -W -Wall -std=gnu99 -masm=intel -g eaxZero.c -o eaxZero
```

gdb instruction:

```
    (gdb)   b 5
..
    (gdb)   r
..
    (gdb)   x/i $eip
..
    (gdb)   x/x $eax
..
    (gdb)   nexti
..
    (gdb)   x/x $eax
..
    (gdb)   nexti
..
    (gdb)   x/x $eax
..
```

Comment: What are you asking?  Do you not know that (anything and 0) == 0?

Comment: I know that 0 AND 0 == 0 but the previous value of eax is a random value !!!

Comment: Then can you not see that (0x454e4f4a and 0x3a313035) == 0?

Comment: for example at the first break point previous the two AND eax == 0xffffdb2C

Comment: note that ((eax and B) and C) == (eax and (B and C)) == (eax and 0)

Comment: but the first AND is (0xffffdb2c AND 0x454e4f4a) and the second is ( eax AND 0x3a313035)

Comment: thank you very much, is this that I don't see